# Interesting Datasets to show the felibility with SVMs in R

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, programming

I hope this is the right place for this question. I am working on a lecture for SMVs. The audience will mostly be beginners. Next to a very graphical theroy presentation I am looking to give two examples on how to use SVMs in R. My idea is to go through the whole process (importing the data to interpreting the SVM model) once. I am now looking for two data sets. A simple one that works well with a linear kernel. And a more complex one where you need a polinomial kernel.

I had thought of something like the setosa datase. My question, however, is whether the forum here knows of more interesting data sets that might be suitable for my project. Interesting refers primarily to the context of the datasets, i.e. something more tangible than the length of flowers ;)

If I am completely wrong in this forum, I would be happy if you could give me a hint where my question would be better placed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the work you've done on this so far. What papers from the SVM literature have you reviewed and rejected as unsuitable, and why? If Setosa classification is uninteresting, then presumably Titanic survivorship and fuel efficiency also are? Would "download a large .CSV from site X" be acceptable, or are we sticking just to popular datasets that are already pre-loaded in the students' environment? (You didn't tell us what the candidate libraries are.)